# Is there a way to use user input to search the api

Tags: javascript, json, string, api

Ok so i am using https://nyaaapi.herokuapp.com/ to fetch the info

to fetch an anime you use [https://nyaaapi.herokuapp.com/nyaa/anime?query={nameofanime}](https://nyaaapi.herokuapp.com/nyaa/anime?query=%7Bnameofanime%7D)

i want to take the name of anime as user-input

i am relatively new to apis and json and i always used random endpoint. I wrote some js but it wasn't remotely correct

```js
const userInput = document.querySelector("#userInput").value;

fetch("https://nyaaapi.herokuapp.com/nyaa/anime?query=${userInput}")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((quote) => console.log(quote));
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>
anime
</title>
</head>
<body>

  <p>
    Anime: <input id="userInput" value="{naruto}" />
    <br />
    <button id="submit">submit</button>
  </p>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What is currently working :
it is sending a request to the api and logging it!

What is currently not working :
while it is sending a request and logging it. I cannot see the relevant information (picture below)

[image]

edit: the third answer is the most useful to my need. I will try to figure out how to show the logged info to the user now

Comment: Yes, of course there is. Please share your attempts such that others can see your problem

Comment: i have added my code!

Comment: Please share more details. What exactly is not working with the given code? What have you tried to make it work?

Comment: You don't call setup. And weatherAsk is not the same as AnimeAsk

Comment: Well currently i want the input to be searched and the api's response to be the result as in when you search a website.

thank you for helping!

Comment: Please add all details to your question by editing it. What **exactly** is not working with the given code? What should it do? What have you tried to make it work?

Comment: added the new code and the problem etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this, it will log to the console the result of the api call when the input gets submitted:

You need an input in your html:

```html
<input id="input" type="text" />
```

And in your js:

```js
function refreshData(e) {
  const nameOfAnime = e.target.value;
  const url = `https://nyaaapi.herokuapp.com/nyaa/anime?query=${nameOfAnime}`;
  fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(console.log);
}

const input = document.getElementById("input");

input.addEventListener("change", refreshData);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way
access the DOM element value using `document.querySelector();`

```
const userInput = document.querySelector("#userInput").value;
```

now use `fetch()` function to make api request.

```
fetch((`https://nyaaapi.herokuapp.com/nyaa/anime?query=${userInput}`).then((data)=>{
       console.log(data);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

I have worked on something similar before. This could give you a start.

```js
window.onload=function(){

        const input = document.getElementById("input");
        const getName = document.getElementById("getName");
        
        
        getName.addEventListener("submit", e =>{
            // Prevent the form from submission
            e.preventDefault();
            // Get city name and store it in local storage
            var inputVal = getName.value;
            var api_url = "{apiurl}" + inputVal;
            // Get the dataset
            function refreshData() {
                fetch(api_url).then(response =>{
                    response.json().then(json => {
                        let dataset = json;
                        let output = formatResponse(dataset);

                    })
                    // Catch error - for example, the user doesn't input a valid name
                    .catch(error => console.log("not ok")); // TO BE IMPROVED
                })

            
        };
});
};
```

```html
<form id="getName" class="search">
            <input type="text" id="input">
            <button id="submit" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```